# Using Joins vs Entity associations

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, navigation-properties

I am learning Entity framework and linq-to-entities.

It's possible to get cross values from multiple tables using JOINS (join keyword) or using the navigation fields ( associations) in which case the framework knows how to reference the cross data.

My question is what to use when?

Comment: Use navigation properties when you CAN use navigation properties:) They are here to make your life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My $0.02: Always use the navigations when you can. Don't use `join` in LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL unless you're forced to. I explain this in much more detail, with examples, here:

[`join` in LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities Considered Messy, Redundant](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/)